# Modify values of date/time text string in HTML with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, integer, calculation

I’d like to convert part of a date/time text string to a number, perform addition/subtraction on it, taking into account the am/pm switch-over at 12:00, and run it behind the original. Possible?

For example, in the existing HTML,

```
<span class="time">12:30pm EST</span>
```

should  display as

```
<span class="time">12:30pm EST / 9:30am PST</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment js library for this. Inside this library, you can pass your current time and convert it to the preferred timezone. Please check the example below:

```js
time = document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0]
var estTime = moment(time.innerHTML, "h:mm A");


var pstTime = estTime.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("h:mm a")

time.innerHTML = time.innerHTML + " / "+pstTime + " PST"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.7/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>

<span class="time">12:30pm EST</span>
```

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you! – one further question, though, if I may. If I add Tokyo time (Asia/Tokyo: EST+14 hours), it will usually but not always go into the following day. How would this script detect that and add a string such as "following day"?

Comment: By using the format method, you can check whether the date is today or the following day. More info: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ Please consider approving the answer if it helped :)

Comment: I'd tried already to approve – but it seems I'm too new to the forum. I shall as soon as I am able! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. Check this example below.

I'm using new ECMAScript features like `const`, `array destructuring` but if can also use `var` and access the array data using the traditional way (`array[0] and array[1]`)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
    // Get the time text
    const time = $('.time').text();
    
    // Split the string in two parts
    const [firstPart, secondPart] = time.split(':');
    
    const hours = Number(firstPart);
    
    // Get only the minutes and discard the rest 
    const minutes = Number(secondPart.substring(0, 2));
    
    // Hours and minutes are numbers, so you can perform addition
    $('#result').text(`${hours + 5}:${minutes}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="time">12:30pm EST</div>

<button id="button">Transform</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you! It's good not to have to load any libraries that are not already running on the site. Please see follow-up question to @Harshana Serasinghe: how to flag a time that usually goes into the following day, as is usual with JST?